# How to parse two file where one file contains the values of variable in another?

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, engineering

I have two files :

file1 : contains the value of the variable.

file2 : contains collection of  steps (subset of collection of file1 ) to follow. Step contains
the set of instructions.

```
 - > file1.txt 
     x1 = 34 
     x2 = 33
     x3 = 90 
     ...
     x12 = 101 
     x14 = 233 
     .. 
     x41 = 901
     ...


 -> file2.txt 

   step 1  
     - x1  
     - x10
     - x11

   step 2 
     - x12 
     - x14 
     - x41

   ..

   step n

   ..
```

**design 1:**

I create class called `storeFile1` and `storeFile2` basically to store what ever is in the file1 and file2.
I also have created respective parser for each of them parseFile1 and parseFile2 which 
populates `storeFile1` and `storeFil2`. Then I place `storeFile1` inside `storeFile2`.

Then when user ask for step1 and its instruction I return a pair of:

```
storeFile2 obj; 
 ... // filled by parsing class first
 obj.get_step("step1");
```

1) name of step  (eg step 2)

2) set of instruction (eg:  {101, 233, 901})

I was wondering if doing this is bad because I break single responsibility principle.

**design 2 :**

What I thought would not break single responsibility principle was to create another class caled `class converter` 
that handles the conversion. 
class `storefile2` returns

> 1) name of step  (eg step 2)
>    2) set of instruction (eg:  {x12,x14, x41})

`class converter` holds class `storeFile1` and class `storeFile2`, does the conversion
and return

> 1) name of step  (eg step 2)
>   2) set of instruction (eg:  {101, 233, 901}) // after conversion

Which one of the two design do you think is good? (I also think design 2 is a little cumbersome) or is there any design better then this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, I would not name your classes `storeFile1`, `storeFile2`, `processFile1`, and `processFile2`. I would give them meaningful names, such as `instructionMapping` for file 1, and `instructionOrder` or `instructionSet` for file 2. I probably use standard existing classes for them (assuming I'm understanding your description correctly).

It looks like file 1 contains a `map` (aka `hash`, aka `dictionary`) that has variable names and their associated values.

It looks like file 2 contains a list of named steps that contain variable names to execute (? or something) in a particular order. So it would also be a `map`, but instead of just a `map` of variable names to values, it would be a map of step names to an `array` (or `vector` or `list`) of variable names that you could look up in the first `map` to get their values.

When building the list of steps contained in file 2, you could simply substitute the variable names for their values as you build it by referencing file 1.

Comment: I will change the name accordingly. So you are saying `instructionSet` contains `instructionMapping` class and the `instructionMapping` is there just for the substitution (via map) ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting.

Comment: one last question though. So `class instructionSet`  would contain something like `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>`.  Then in line where you said, `When building the list of steps contained in file 2, you could simply substitute the variable names for their values as you build it by referencing file 1.`  you mean building return value? for eg: when user request a specific step, by doing something like `obj.get_step("step2");` eg: step 2 we return `std::vector<int>` eg ` {101, 233, 901}`

Comment: Exactly! It seems like an easy way to do it unless you need the variable names in order for some other purpose.